# Difference in the domain while setting cookie using javascript document.cookie="domain=" v/s document.cookie="domain:"

Tags: javascript, cookies

When setting cookie in javascript using `document.cookie="dom_x=yyy;domain=www.mozilla.org;path=/"`, the cookie gets set in the domain `www.mozilla.org`.

At the same time while using `document.cookie="dom_x_dot=yyy;domain:www.mozilla.org;path=/"` the cookies get set in the domain `.www.mozilla.org`.

Is the syntax `document.cookie="dom_x_dot=yyy;domain:www.mozilla.org;path=/"` valid and if so when does it need to be used?

Comment: I think the difference is browser specific.

Comment: I had tried this in Google Chrome and Firefox in Mac. The results were consistent in both the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a cookie domain that starts with a `dot`, like '`.www.mozilla.org`', it will be sent to that domain but also `all subdomains` of that domain like '`sub.www.mozilla.org`'. Without the `dot` it will only be send to the exact domain '`www.mozilla.org`'.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But what am really looking is for, is the validity of the following syntax **document.cookie="dom_x_dot=yyy;domain:www.mozilla.org;path=/"**